# Not able to get only date form my asp .net calendar control

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp .net calendar control. But when I try to fetch date from my calender

```
 string date1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

my date1 value is ("19-03-2020 12.00.00 AM")

what I want = "19-03-2020"

I have tried different conversion none of them work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call ToString() you are asking a datetime variable to represent itself as a string without giving it any hint how do you want that string to be formatted.

```
string date1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

will give you the output required.

DateTime variables are not strings. How do you format them to be displayed on your output devices is up to you and to [the proper formatting string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)